# Do i need to "didReceiveRegistrationToken"?

Tags: ios, firebase, swiftui, token

I want to send notifications, but only to authenticated users. This means, if my token updates (potential reasons: app is restored on a new device, user uninstalls/reinstall the app or user clears app data) my user will also not be authenticated.

Thus, whenever my user tries to login i update the token, which i receive via this method, for my backend:

```
Messaging.messaging().token { token, error in
    // ...
}
```

When the user logs out i delete the token, so why would i implement this method here:

```
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?) {
    
}
```

However, if i do not implement it, i receive this:

```
9.5.0 - [FirebaseMessaging][I-FCM002023] The object <Name.Delegate: 0x2827c0650> does not respond to -messaging:didReceiveRegistrationToken:. Please implement -messaging:didReceiveRegistrationToken: to be provided with an FCM token.
```

Answer (score 0):

In this function you must Save your device "**Token**" or "**refresh token**" as Local:

```
"didReceiveRegistrationToken"
```

When the user logged in you must register the push-token in the backend

When the user logged out you must clear the push-token in the backend

You must after login set a key value in **"KeyChain"** such as:

```
"userId" : "x"
```

**"For the users that before login, cleared or uninstalled the app"**:

In each launch you must check your app user is login or not?

if "**NO**" (doesn't have the token):

You must clear the push-token with "userId -> x" that you saved on keychain. (request it to the backend)

Albeit the new push-token is different with the previouse push-token.

if "**YES**" (user had backend token)

you must save the new "push-token" or "refresh-push-token" from below function:

```
"didReceiveRegistrationToken"
```

Comment: But, since i have to check the auth maually anyways, i can update my token with the above specified method `Messaging.messaging().token()`, which delivers the token aswell (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#fetching-the-current-registration-token).

Comment: You must update your push-token in "didReceiveRegistrationToken" because of FCM push refresh token